# HTML shows graph when clicked on but not when accessed in flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, graph

*Am completely new to flask so pls forgive me if dumb question*

I'm learning how to use flask and want display graphs generated by sigma.js.

When I open "svg-freestyle-renderer.html" directly by double-clicking on the file, it opens up and shows an interactable network graph with nodes and connections.

Now I want to view the same graph by accessing the html in a flask server but when I open the page, it only loads the background colour without the graph. I've triple checked all my files are in the right directory.

Is there a difference between opening a html file directly and accessing it through flask that I'm missing?

This is how I'm calling the html in my py file:

```
@app.route("/graph")
def draw_graph():
        return render_template('svg-freestyle-renderer.html')
```

And this is the .html:

```
<html>

<body>

<!-- START SIGMA IMPORTS -->
<script src="../src/sigma.core.js"></script>
<script src="../src/conrad.js"></script>
<script src="../src/utils/sigma.utils.js"></script>
<script src="../src/utils/sigma.polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="../src/sigma.settings.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.dispatcher.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.configurable.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.graph.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.camera.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.quad.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.edgequad.js"></script>
<script src="../src/captors/sigma.captors.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="../src/captors/sigma.captors.touch.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.canvas.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.webgl.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.svg.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.nodes.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.nodes.fast.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.fast.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.arrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.labels.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.hovers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.nodes.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curve.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.arrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curvedArrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edgehovers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edgehovers.curve.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edgehovers.arrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edgehovers.curvedArrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.extremities.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.utils.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.nodes.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.edges.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.edges.curve.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.labels.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.hovers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/middlewares/sigma.middlewares.rescale.js"></script>
<script src="../src/middlewares/sigma.middlewares.copy.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.animation.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.bindEvents.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.bindDOMEvents.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.drawHovers.js"></script>
<!-- END SIGMA IMPORTS -->
<script src="../plugins/sigma.plugins.neighborhoods/sigma.plugins.neighborhoods.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/supervisor.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/worker.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <style>
    #graph-container {
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #455660;
    }
    .sigma-edge {
      stroke: #14191C;
    }
    .sigma-node {
      fill: green;
      stroke: #14191C;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    .sigma-node:hover {
      fill: blue;
    }
    .muted {
      fill-opacity: 0.1;
      stroke-opacity: 0.1;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>

<script>
/**
 * This is a basic example of how one could spawn a freestyle svg renderer
 * to achieve his/her goal through css and jQuery to display fancy graphs
 * but somewhat less performant.
 */
var i,
    s,
    N = 100,
    E = 500,
    g = {
      nodes: [],
      edges: []
    };

// Generate a random graph:
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  g.nodes.push({
    id: 'n' + i,
    label: 'Node ' + i,
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
    size: Math.random(),
    color: '#666'
  });

for (i = 0; i < E; i++)
  g.edges.push({
    id: 'e' + i,
    source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    target: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    size: Math.random(),
    color: '#ccc'
  });

// Instantiate sigma:
s = new sigma({
  graph: g,
  settings: {
    enableHovering: false
  }
});

s.addRenderer({
  id: 'main',
  type: 'svg',
  container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
  freeStyle: true
});

s.refresh();

// Binding silly interactions
function mute(node) {
  if (!~node.getAttribute('class').search(/muted/))
    node.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', node.getAttribute('class') + ' muted');
}

function unmute(node) {
  node.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', node.getAttribute('class').replace(/(\s|^)muted(\s|$)/g, '$2'));
}

$('.sigma-node').click(function() {

  // Muting
  $('.sigma-node, .sigma-edge').each(function() {
    mute(this);
  });

  // Unmuting neighbors
  var neighbors = s.graph.neighborhood($(this).attr('data-node-id'));
  neighbors.nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    unmute($('[data-node-id="' + node.id + '"]')[0]);
  });

  neighbors.edges.forEach(function(edge) {
    unmute($('[data-edge-id="' + edge.id + '"]')[0]);
  });
});

s.bind('clickStage', function() {
  $('.sigma-node, .sigma-edge').each(function() {
    unmute(this);
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a tree of your project directory and files? it sounds like your `.html` file is not able to find your scripts. does the browser console have any errors in it?

Comment: use `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome to see if there is  no erorr message in JavaScript console and if it has no problems to load JavaScript files. `Flask` usually serves static files (like `.js`) from folder `static` and if you use other folder then it may not find it.

Comment: OH yep you're so right, seems like my files aren't in the right place after all. I'm getting ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND) for all of the sigma imports.

EDIT: okay I have no idea how to type out a list but all my folders are on the same level (src, plugins, static, templates) and the .html is in the templates folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your page in browser and click "Inspect element" and open "console". You'll see something like

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

for all your files.

Put your js files in a directory named `static` or you can specify your own creating your app `app = Flask(static_folder="src")`

And in your templates use `{{ url_for('static', filename='sigma.core.js') }}` to access your js-files. You won't be able to open this page in browser directly from filesystem, but will it perfectly served by app.

Links about [static files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/) and [app API](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/) for reference.

Comment: THANK YOU TO THE HIGH HEAVENS AND BEYOND